# PC address for JSR

Tags: lc3

I have this block of code and I was wondering what address would be stored in the PC. From what I can see, it seems to be x3002 but im not quite sure.

```
.ORIG x3000
JSR FOO
ADD R0,R4,R2
FOO: ADD R0,R0,#1
 RET
```

If it is not x3002 could you please let me know as to why this would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

JSR will simply store into the PC the address of the label.

FOO is at x3002.
so PC will jump to x3002 and R7 will have the value x3001.